# PHP-como atualizar os values num combobox depois de clicar no botao inserir?

Tags: php, html, css, combobox, dropdownlist

sou nova em programming e estudo sozinha...quebrei minha cabeca hj no projeto da escola..Preciso fazer com que apos o usuario fazer o registro de um curso escolhendo na combobox e clicando enroll, seja feita a gravacao na tabela enroll no banco de dados. OK, ate ai esta funcionando.O problema eh que como o usuario continua logado, a combobox nao da um refresh, ou seja, ele pode selecionar o mesmo curso 2 X, e isso nao pode acontecer...POR FAVOR, como faco pra atualizar os valores da combobox logo apos clicar no enroll botao e sem que isso interfira na insercao dos dados na tabela? alguem me ajuda!!!! grata desde ja!!

```html
<?php  //this is panel.php
session_start();
include('userauthentication.php');
include ('header.php');
include ('connection.php');
?>
<?php

$result_courses=$conn->query("SELECT * FROM courses");

$color1="whitesmoke";
$color2="teal";
$color= $color1;

?>

<html><head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="school.css"/>
<title>Course enrollment</title>

</head>
<body>
<div id="student">
<h3><p> Haven't you enroll in a course yet?</p><h3>        
<p>Choose your options:</p>
<form name="courses" method="post" action="enroll.php">
<select name="courses" > 
<?php
while($rows= $result_courses->fetch_assoc())
{
 $color == $color1 ? $color= $color2 : $color= $color1;
 
 $idcourse=$rows['idcourse'];
 $title= $rows['title'];
 
 echo "<option value='$idcourse' style='background:$color;'>$title</option>";
 
}

?>
<input  type="submit" name="submit" value="Enroll">
</form>
</div>

<div id="footer">
<?php  include ('footer.php');?>
   
 </div>
</body>
</html>

/////////////here enroll.php///////
<?php
session_start();
include('userauthentication.php');
include('connection.php');

if(isset($_POST['courses']))
{ 


    /*.. do the query ... */
 $idstudent=$_SESSION['idstudent'];
 $idcourse=$_POST['courses'];
 
  $query= "INSERT INTO enroll VALUES(null,'".$idstudent."','".$idcourse."')";
  
  $result=mysqli_query($conn,$query);
      
      if(!$result)
   {
   echo "INSERT failed<br><br>";
   
  header('Location:panel.php');
   }
 
}

?>
```

Comment: você pode utilizar uma função em javascript para fazer isso : `document.getElementsByName('enroll').addEventListener("submit", window.location.reload());`

Comment: Quando se trata de manipulação sem refresh na página você pode usar o AJAX com JS que vai lhe ajudar bem.

Comment: Muito obrigada!!!